# How to penalize the loss of one class more than the other in tensorflow for a multi class problem?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, loss-function

Let's say my model has two classes Class 1 and Class 2. Both Class 1 and Class 2 has a equal amount of training and testing data. But I want to penalize the loss of the Class 1 more than Class 2, so that one class has a fewer number of False Positives than the other (**I want the model to perform better for one class than the other**).

How do I achieve this in **Tensorflow**?

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are looking for is probably
[`weighted_cross_entropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits). 
It is giving a very closely related contextual information, similar to @Sazzad 's answer, but specific to TensorFlow. To quote the documentation:

> This is like `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits()` except that
>   pos_weight, allows one to trade off recall and precision by up- or
>   down-weighting the cost of a positive error relative to a negative
>   error.

It accepts an additional argument `pos_weights`. Also note that this is only for *binary* classification, which is the case in the example you described. If there might be other classes besides the two, this would **not** work.

Comment: What will be the value of pos_weights ?

Comment: "A coefficient to use on the positive examples." This can be any real number, weighting your positive samples *more* (or *less*) by the given factor. Again, see the other answer for a mathematical description of this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this is not a tensorflow concept. you can write your own. for binary classification, the loss is something like this

> loss = ylogy + (1-y)log(1-y)

Here class 0 and class 1 have the same weight in the loss. So you can give more give more weight to some portion. for example,

> loss =  **5** * ylogy + (1-y)log(1-y)

Hope it answers your question.